# SQLite in Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, sqlite, xamarin.ios

When I try to create a SQLite Database in the Xamarin Android Project, I get the following Exception.

> System.Exception: Something went wrong in the build configuration. 
>   This is the bait assembly, which is for referencing by portable
>   libraries, and should never end up part of the app.  Reference the
>   appropriate platform assembly instead.

One thing I found already out is that I need SQLite.Net.SQLitePlatform for Android. I dont have the SQLite.Net Namespace.

I used the [SQLite.net PCL NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

```
I am creating the DB Path in the MainActivity.cs of the Droid Project

    var sqliteFilename = "timesheet.db3";
    string libraryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
```

In the Forms app I am trying to create the Database

```
database = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
database.CreateTable<TimeRecordEntity>();
```

Comment: did you install the package in BOTH your platform (iOS, Android, etc) AND PCL projects?

Comment: Yes I installed it on BOTH platforms and PCL projects